# Why is my getRoute() function called multiple times when using futureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

When using FutureBuilder, why is getRoute() function being called at least twice? Here userInfoDao is my local storage, I'm retrieving a flag from there which tells whether the user is already logged in or not and based on that the user is being routed to either login page or the activities page. getRoute() gets called even when I'm routed to the activities page, and because of that the activitesPage's initState is being called multiple. Any information shedding light on this problem will be greatly appreciated.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(HomePage());
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  HomePage();

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  UserInfoDao userInfoDao;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    userInfoDao = new UserInfoDao();
    NotificationOperations();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MaterialApp(
            theme: new ThemeData(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue, primaryColor: Colors.blue),
            initialRoute: snapshot.data,
            onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
          );
        } else {
          return new Center(
            child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
      future: getRoute(),
    );
  }

  Future getRoute() async {
    print("main");
    bool flag = await userInfoDao.getValue("loggedIn");
    if (flag != null) {
      if (flag == true) {
        return '/activitiesPage';
      } else
        return '/loginPage';
    }
    return '/loginPage';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store Future object in State:

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  UserInfoDao userInfoDao;
  Future future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    userInfoDao = new UserInfoDao();
    NotificationOperations();
    future = getRoute();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MaterialApp(
            theme: new ThemeData(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue, primaryColor: Colors.blue),
            initialRoute: snapshot.data,
            onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
          );
        } else {
          return new Center(
            child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
      future: future,
    );
  }

  Future getRoute() async {
    print("main");
    bool flag = await userInfoDao.getValue("loggedIn").then((flag){});
    if (flag != null) {
      if (flag == true) {
        return '/activitiesPage';
      } else
        return '/loginPage';
    }
    return '/loginPage';
  }
}
```

From [FutureBuilder docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html):

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
>   State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or
>   State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the
>   State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the
>   FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Try method `runOnce()` in `AsyncMemoizer` class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/AsyncMemoizer-class.html)

Remember install async: 2.4.0 or [higher](https://pub.dev/packages/async#-installing-tab-)